# Triangle Aim jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a new project where I wanted to try using jQuery.
I have a idea of slow moving arrow on `:hover`.
I cannot seem to find any tutorials on how to do it, and I know I saw it somewhere.
Could you please help me find or at least help me list out how to do it?

You can see what I mean in the link with picture below:

[image]

Comment: Do you learn everything through tutorials? You should experiment, that's how you truly learn.

Comment: @Kolink I cannot experiment if I do not know the language yet

Comment: You're telling me you don't know any JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, I did not have the chance to begin with it yet, but it would be nice to know how to do that menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use .animate() to move a absolute positioned div across the menu